# NavigationComponent with BottomNavigationView fragment progress

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm using NavigationComponent with BottomNavigationView.

I'm facing with a problem thats when i select first item in BottomNavigationView then go from fragment 1->2->3 after that i change selection to second item in BottomNavigationView. When i reselect first item in BottomNavigationView i'm losing fragment progress in first selected item.

[The scheme of what is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se6AU.png)

[A scheme of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4iaV.png)

How can i manage it?